SSH in VSCode with Remote SSH and WSL
I need to use SSH to connect to Grid5000 (www.grid5000.fr).
While I can easily do it from the terminal, I saw this extension Remote SSH on VSCode that allows to connect with SSH in VSCode.
The problem is, I'm working on WSL2 and when I try to connect to Grid5000 using VSCode, but I cant. I've read this post (Can I SSH from WSL in Visual Studio Code?) and tried the ssh.bat method but it's not working.
I see some bugged characters (line [18:29:41.745] and [18:29:41.776]), it might just be this.
Specs :
Windows 11
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (WSL2)

VSCode settings :
Remote.SSH: Config File
C:\Users\bapti\config

Remote.SSH: Path
C:\Users\bapti\ssh.bat

config in /home/bmouillon/.ssh (Actually I think this file is useless, if I understood well)
Host g5k
  User bmouillo
  HostName access.grid5000.fr
  ForwardAgent no

Host *.g5k
  User bmouillo
  ProxyCommand ssh g5k -W "$(basename %h .g5k):%p"
  ForwardAgent no
 
Host dahu-23.grenoble.g5k
  HostName dahu-23.grenoble.g5k

config in C:\Users\bapti :
Host g5k
  User bmouillo
  HostName access.grid5000.fr
  ForwardAgent no

Host *.g5k
  User bmouillo
  ProxyCommand ssh g5k -W "$(basename %h .g5k):%p"
  ForwardAgent no
 
Host dahu-23.grenoble.g5k
  HostName dahu-23.grenoble.g5k

ssh.bat in C:\Users\bapti
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe ssh %*

Logs :
[18:29:39.904] Log Level: 2
[18:29:39.909] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+dahu-23.grenoble.g5k", attempt 1
[18:29:39.910] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[18:29:39.910] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[18:29:39.910] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[18:29:39.910] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[18:29:39.910] "remote.SSH.path": C:\Users\bapti\ssh.bat
[18:29:39.910] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\bapti\config
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.permitPtyAllocation": false
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.preferredLocalPortRange: undefined
[18:29:39.911] "remote.SSH.useCurlAndWgetConfigurationFiles: false
[18:29:39.917] VS Code version: 1.93.1
[18:29:39.917] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.114.3
[18:29:39.917] win32 x64
[18:29:39.919] SSH Resolver called for host: dahu-23.grenoble.g5k
[18:29:39.919] Setting up SSH remote "dahu-23.grenoble.g5k"
[18:29:39.922] Using commit id "38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40" and quality "stable" for server
[18:29:39.924] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "51980278fa2f",
  "startMarker": "51980278fa2f: running",
  "commitId": "38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "11a1a111-a1a1-1111-1111-111111a11aa1",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "1",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "51980278fa2f:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "51980278fa2f:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "51980278fa2f%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "51980278fa2f%%2%%"
}
[18:29:39.926] Install and start server if needed
[18:29:41.436] Checking ssh with "C:\Users\bapti\ssh.bat -V"
[18:29:41.476] stdout> 
C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code>C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe ssh -V 

[18:29:41.509] > OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

[18:29:41.552] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\bapti\config"
[18:29:41.553] Running script with connection command: "C:\Users\bapti\ssh.bat" -T -D 63247 -F "C:\Users\bapti\config" "dahu-23.grenoble.g5k" sh
[18:29:41.554] Generated SSH command: 'type "C:\Users\bapti\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-dahu-23.grenoble.g5k-319673841.sh" | "C:\Users\bapti\ssh.bat" -T -D 63247 -F "C:\Users\bapti\config" "dahu-23.grenoble.g5k" sh'
[18:29:41.555] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[18:29:41.745] > [?9001h[?1004h
[18:29:41.745] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[18:29:41.776] > ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[18:29:41.790] > C:\Users\bapti>C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe ssh -T -D 63247 -F "C:\Users\bapti\config" "dahu-23.grenoble.g5k" sh 
[18:29:41.805] > Can't open user config file C:\\Users\\bapti\\config: No such file or directory
[18:29:43.107] "install" terminal command done
[18:29:43.107] Install terminal quit with output: Can't open user config file C:\\Users\\bapti\\config: No such file or directory
[18:29:43.107] Received install output: Can't open user config file C:\\Users\\bapti\\config: No such file or directory
[18:29:43.108] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[18:29:43.109] Resolver error: Error: 
    at v.Create (c:\Users\bapti\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3\out\extension.js:2:501404)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\bapti\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3\out\extension.js:2:498726)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\bapti\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3\out\extension.js:2:616460)
    at async c:\Users\bapti\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3\out\extension.js:2:575788
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\bapti\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3\out\extension.js:2:579017)
    at async k (c:\Users\bapti\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3\out\extension.js:2:572574)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\bapti\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3\out\extension.js:2:576428)
    at async c:\Users\bapti\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3\out\extension.js:2:844803
[18:29:43.112] ------




[18:29:43.341] Opening exec server for ssh-remote+dahu-23.grenoble.g5k
[18:29:43.349] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+dahu-23.grenoble.g5k
[18:29:43.350] Using commit id "38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40" and quality "stable" for server
[18:29:43.352] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "bee78580ca77",
  "startMarker": "bee78580ca77: running",
  "commitId": "38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "a111a111-a1aa-1111-11aa-1111a1aaa1a1",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "1",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "bee78580ca77:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "bee78580ca77:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "bee78580ca77%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "bee78580ca77%%2%%"
}
[18:29:43.353] Install and start server if needed
[18:29:46.820] getPlatformForHost was canceled
[18:29:46.820] Exec server for ssh-remote+dahu-23.grenoble.g5k failed: Error: Connecting was canceled
[18:29:46.820] Error opening exec server for ssh-remote+dahu-23.grenoble.g5k: Error: Connecting was canceled

